# Track element is not working with audio element

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to use the track element with audio element but it is not working for me, can someone give me some guidance 
Looking in my console I dont see an error but i see this 
Resource interpreted as TextTrack but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://127.0.0.1/output_trim.vtt".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>


<audio  width="900" height="900" controls >
   <source src="output_trim.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="http://127.0.0.1/output_trim.vtt" default>
   
   
</video>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look in the console and see if there is an error, if so, include it in your question, if there is no error mention that in your question as wel. F12 and click the "console" tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading a webm audio file as the src attribute for a video element. Then you can set the length and width attributes of the video element so it looks like a music player. I've done this using the URL.createObjectURL() to play local audio with .vtt files on my drive but I'm not sure about other use cases.

Comment: Actually decreasing the video element height made the subtitle size ridiculously small. Will have to find a way to format it so that font size ignores the video element height.